# OxyPlot LineAnnotation Visibility in WPF and XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, oxyplot

I have configured an Oxyplot in XAML, using Plot, not PlotView. (I am using Binding on individual properties, rather than on the complete PlotModel.)

The configuration uses 6 LineAnnotations, which I want to show or hide optionally.

I have used Binding to connect the Visibility property of the LineAnnotations to properties in my ViewModel. The properties are boolean and I have used a converter to convert the value to Visibility.Collapsed or Visibility.Visible (but I could just as well have defined a property with the type Visibility).

This doesn't work. The LineAnnotations are always visible.

In fact, I don't think that the Visibility property of a LineAnnotation works at all.

Can anybody confirm this problem?

Is there an alternative way to show or hide LineAnnotations based on a property in my ViewModel?

I would prefer to stick with the XAML configuration, rather than add and remove the LineAnnotations in code.

**Update**

As requested, some code

Xaml

```
<oxy:Plot Grid.Row="1">
  <oxy:Plot.Axes>
    <oxy:LinearAxis Key="yAxis"
                    Position="{Binding Path=XAxisInverted, Converter={StaticResource BoolToAxisPosition_fl_tr}}"
                    Minimum="{Binding YAxis_Min}"
                    Maximum="{Binding YAxis_Max}"
                    MajorGridlineStyle="Dot"
                    MajorGridlineColor="LightGray"
                    Title="Velocity [km/h]" />
    <oxy:LinearAxis Key="xAxis"
                    Position="Bottom"
                    Minimum="{Binding XAxisNumericMin}"
                    Maximum="{Binding XAxisNumericMax}"
                    StartPosition="{Binding Path=XAxisInverted, Converter={StaticResource BoolToInt_f0_t1}}"
                    EndPosition="{Binding Path=XAxisInverted, Converter={StaticResource BoolToInt_f1_t0}}"
                    MajorGridlineStyle="Dot"
                    MajorGridlineColor="LightGray"
                    Title="Position [m]" />
  </oxy:Plot.Axes>
  <oxy:Plot.Series>
    <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding PointsRef1}"
                    DataFieldX="X"
                    DataFieldY="Y"
                    StrokeThickness="1"
                    MarkerSize="0"
                    LineStyle="Solid"
                    Color="DarkGray"
                    MarkerType="None"/>
    <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding PointsRef2}"
                    DataFieldX="X"
                    DataFieldY="Y"
                    StrokeThickness="1"
                    MarkerSize="0"
                    LineStyle="Solid"
                    Color="DarkGray"
                    MarkerType="None"/>
    <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding PointsBlack}"
                    DataFieldX="X"
                    DataFieldY="Y"
                    StrokeThickness="1"
                    MarkerSize="0"
                    LineStyle="Solid"
                    Color="Black"
                    MarkerType="None"/>
    <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding PointsRed}"
                    DataFieldX="X"
                    DataFieldY="Y"
                    StrokeThickness="1"
                    MarkerSize="0"
                    LineStyle="Solid"
                    Color="Red"
                    MarkerType="None"/>
    <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding PointsBlue}"
                    DataFieldX="X"
                    DataFieldY="Y"
                    StrokeThickness="1"
                    MarkerSize="0"
                    LineStyle="Solid"
                    Color="Blue"
                    MarkerType="None"/>
    <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding PointsGreen}"
                    DataFieldX="X"
                    DataFieldY="Y"
                    StrokeThickness="1"
                    MarkerSize="0"
                    LineStyle="Solid"
                    Color="Green"
                    MarkerType="None"/>
  </oxy:Plot.Series>
  <oxy:Plot.Annotations>
    <oxy:LineAnnotation x:Name="BrakePosRear"   Type="Vertical" Color="{Binding BrakePosRear_1_Color}"  Visibility="{Binding Path=BrakePosRear_1_Enabled,  Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}" X="{Binding BrakePosRear_1_Value}"  local:AnnotationDragableBehavior.IsDragable="True" />
    <oxy:LineAnnotation x:Name="BrakePosFront"  Type="Vertical" Color="{Binding BrakePosFront_1_Color}" Visibility="{Binding Path=BrakePosFront_1_Enabled, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}" X="{Binding BrakePosFront_1_Value}" local:AnnotationDragableBehavior.IsDragable="True" />
    <oxy:LineAnnotation x:Name="RefPos"         Type="Vertical" Color="{Binding RefPos_1_Color}"        Visibility="{Binding Path=RefPos_1_Enabled,        Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}" X="{Binding RefPos_1_Value}"        local:AnnotationDragableBehavior.IsDragable="True" />
    <oxy:LineAnnotation x:Name="BrakePosRear2"  Type="Vertical" Color="{Binding BrakePosRear_2_Color}"  Visibility="{Binding Path=BrakePosRear_2_Enabled,  Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}" X="{Binding BrakePosRear_2_Value}"  local:AnnotationDragableBehavior.IsDragable="True" />
    <oxy:LineAnnotation x:Name="BrakePosFront2" Type="Vertical" Color="{Binding BrakePosFront_2_Color}" Visibility="{Binding Path=BrakePosFront_2_Enabled, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}" X="{Binding BrakePosFront_2_Value}" local:AnnotationDragableBehavior.IsDragable="True" />
    <oxy:LineAnnotation x:Name="RefPos2"        Type="Vertical" Color="{Binding RefPos_2_Color}"        Visibility="{Binding Path=RefPos_2_Enabled,        Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}" X="{Binding RefPos_2_Value}"        local:AnnotationDragableBehavior.IsDragable="True" />
  </oxy:Plot.Annotations>
</oxy:Plot>
```

The type converter

```
class BoolToVisibility : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
  {
    return System.Convert.ToBoolean ( value ) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed ;
  }

  public object ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException ();
  }
}
```

I also have an attached behavior to handle mouse events on the LineAnnotation (which is pretty cool), but I don't think it is relevant.

I have also tried specifying Visibility="Collapsed" (and also "Hidden") directly in XAML, but it has no effect.

Even if the binding was not working, hard coding the value in XAML ought to work.

Comment: Show us some code, so we can see, if there is something wrong with it.

Comment: Try setting the color of the lineseries to transparent. I know that is not the best solution but I have had the same problem and it worked for me.

Comment: If you look up the Visual Tree, you'll see that there's no `LineAnnotation` entity anymore, that you could even possibly inspect the value of the `Visibility` property. It is all gone, broken down into basic components such as `Polyline`, `Path`, `TextBlock`, etc.

Comment: @Kirenenko I tried StrokeThickness=0 which kind of worked, but it still handled mouse events, which in my application was a problem. At present I am setting the X position outside the visible area, which works OK for now.

Comment: @jstreet, thanks, I will look at that. My code is actually running in an old C++ application and I don't think there is an easy way to look at the visual tree. I will have to make a small test application.

Comment: @PhilJollans if you're using Visual Studio just select **Debug/Windows/Live Visual Tree**.

Comment: @jstreet That shows me an empty window. My WPF window is in  WinForms host control, which is ComVisible and loaded as an ActiveX control in an MFC application (literally from the last century). It's a wonder that it works at all. I will make a test app in pure WPF to view the visual tree.

Answer (score 4):

In the current implementation of OxyPlot and OxyPlot.Wpf this will not work.

The class OxyPlot.Wpf.LineAnnotation is a wrapper for the internal class OxyPlot.LineAnnotation. To handle the Visiblilty property, it would have to map the property to an appropriate property of the internal LineAnnotation class.

There are two problems. Not only does Wpf.LineAnnotation not handle the Visiblilty property, but there is no underlying property in the LineAnnotation class to which it could be mapped. The LineAnnotation class doesn't appear to have any concept of making itself hidden.

This is a mismatch between OxyPlot and XAML. As jstreet has pointed out, LineAnnotation does not appear in the Visual Tree at all.

Comment: A fairly easy workaround it to set StrokeThickness=0 to hide the LineAnnotation. This can be set with Binding.

Comment: Another possibility besides StrokeThickness is to set the Color to Transparent, or another color with "alpha" set to zero. And that because `Opacity` doesn't seem to work, either...